# Is total number of modifiers in X11 window system constant?

Tags: x11, xserver

In all of the linux machines running X11 as the window system has total 8 modifier keys https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key. Can the number of modifier keys be increased through configuration ?. Can new modifier keys be defined ?